# ssh multiple host (host B via host A) through php

Tags: php, ssh

I want to ssh host A from web host, and ssh host B from host A via libssh2-php package in PHP.

Is it possible?

I know package libssh2-php that execute one ssh connect.

Like this:

In web host connect to hostA.

```
$conn = ssh2_connect($hostA, $portA);
```

But I want to connect to hostB from hostA.

Please help me.

Comment: What do you want to do on host B?

Comment: I want to execute instructions on host B.

Answer (score 0):

The PHP libssh2 library does support connection tunneling, see the [`ssh2_tunnel` function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-tunnel.php):

```
resource ssh2_tunnel ( resource $session , string $host , int $port )
```

But the function does return a socket stream. I'm afraid there's no way to bind that socket stream back to libssh2 to run another SSH session on top of it.

So my conclusion is, that there's no native way to do this in PHP (using the libssh2).

---

You can run the command-line `ssh` from the PHP instead. For that you have to setup some kind of automatic login. You will find plenty of resources online.

You can for example setup a special a private key on the "host B" that allow executing only the instructions you need (using the `command` directive in the `authorized_keys`). Then, store an un-encrypted key on the "host A".

In PHP, use the `ssh2_exec` to execute the command-line `ssh` from the "host A" using the private key, to execute the instructions on the "host B".

Comment: Yes,you are right.
 I find another approach , but I don't understand hwo to do.
It say "you will need to pipe all the data from the tunnel socket and a socket_listen. That easy right? Wrong. PHP doesn't allow threaded execution so you'll need to pcntl_fork a proc off to do the piping. "

Could you help me?

Comment: hello, you say that like this: ssh_exec($conn,'ssh -i id_rsa root@ip ls -al') ?

Comment: Yes that's correct. The `$conn` should refer to an existing SSH connection to "Host A".

Comment: So Is there no approach to keep connection,right?
because I need to other exec like openShell.

Comment: Well everything is possible, but it would be a way more difficult to implement.

Comment: Yes, you are right.I found for a long time,but I can't find a way that solve my probelm,so sad.

Comment: Your answer did not solved my problem. But thank you for help.

Comment: Maybe if you make a donation to the phpseclib author they can add tunneling to it. I've found them to be pretty receptive to that.

Comment: @user5290752 While it did not solve your problem, it did answer your question *"Is it possible?"*